# How to target/animate a div with general sibling selector ~?

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how general sibling selectors work with targeting/triggering/animating divs. I can't see the reason why it doesn't move image class to show the other images..

```
input.img_link1:checked ~ .image {top: 0; }
input.img_link2:checked ~ .image {top: -500px; }
input.img_link3:checked ~ .image {top: -1000px; }
input.img_link4:checked ~ .image {top: -1500px; }
```

Here is the entire code:
http://jsfiddle.net/UeNxy

Comment: The images and inputs are in different containers and therefore are not siblings.

Comment: `input.img_link1[checked] .image .....` and so on

Comment: @EL your code implies that the image is INSIDE the input, which is impossible, since input is an empty element

Comment: Actually, the code isn't implying that at all.

Comment: Your code can't work because they're not siblings, and because the `.image` elements appear *before* the `input` that you're checking/unchecking. Now, what is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: You could put the images in their own div and do it this way `input:checked ~ .imageDiv > .image` http://jsfiddle.net/5ebd3/

Comment: @brouxhaha Just came back to add it:) so actually we can call siblings of a div(to style) as the input:checked! Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because the inputs aren't siblings of the images in your example. They have different parents. For them to be siblings, they would both have to be inside the same div, so something like this:

```
<div class="frame">
    <input type="radio" class="link img_link2" name="select-img" />
    <input type="radio" class="link img_link3" name="select-img" />
    <input type="radio" class="link img_link3" name="select-img" />
    <input type="radio" class="link img_link4" name="select-img" />
    <img class="image" src="img1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="img1" />
    <img class="image" src="img1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="img2" />
    <img class="image" src="img1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="img3" />
    <img class="image" src="img1.jpg" alt="image 1" id="img4" />
</div>
```

Comment: This still won't work because the sibling has to be (anywhere) after the first element. YES: `#img1 ~ .img_link1` / NO: `.img_link1 ~ #img1`

Comment: You're right, I wasn't thinking about that part of it. Updated to reflect that